# android webview shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not calling

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to load URL in webview But it does not calling shouldOverrideUrlLoading

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //   webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
//        webview.loadUrl("http://www.androidexample.com/media/webview/login.html");
        webview.loadUrl(URL_TO_LOAD);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {

                Log.d("URL!!!! ", url);
                Log.d("message!!!! ", message);
              //  Log.d("URL!!!! ", url);

                return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
                // System.out.println("url = " + url);

            }
        });
```

and this is my class

```
 private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                if (progressDialog == null) {
                    // in standard case YourActivity.this
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TestWv.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                System.out.println("onPageFinished = ");
                try {
                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

it works proper if i pass google.com... it works properly... but if i am passing my URL it does not calling  shouldOverrideUrlLoading or onPageFinished method.. what should the problem?

Please Help...

Comment: Was there any logcats or any exceptions for putting it here?

Comment: no nothing in logcat...

Comment: can u tell what's your url and how u did the input?

Comment: @Brendon - you can see that url on above codes

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable dom storage with:

```
 webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(false);
```

and see if shouldOverrideUrlLoading will be called now.